# Uncertainty of parameters estimated by maximum likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, uncertainty

For different sample sizes we will get different estimate of parameters by MLE. Can this size(n) be related to uncertainty in those MLE estimated parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely: it is called the Cramér-Rao bound (see the [wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound)).

The Cramér-Rao bound gives you a lower bound on the variance of an unbiased estimator (a modification of the inequality for biased estimator also exists). The variance of your estimator will always be at least as large as the inverse of the Fisher Information, which is itself a function of the number of data points $n$. If your data are IID, the Fisher Information will be $n$ times the Fisher Information for one observation (see the [properties of the Fisher Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Chain_rule)).

This can be understood intuitively: the more data points you have, the more information you have, and hence you have a more precise inference of $\theta$ (i.e. the variance of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ decreases).

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted :)