# Repeated measurements needed for certainty

Tags: confidence-interval, repeated-measures, noise, variability

A bit of a silly question.

We have a model, which can be described as *y* = *M*(x) + some significant levels of noise.

We see that if we repeat the measurements of *y* N times, we can see a clear correlation between the measurements and *M*.

However we want to present the data in a different format, mainly answering the question "how many repeated measurements of the same object *x* are needed to get a good estimate of *M*(x)?"

Is there a statistical framework for that?

Comment: Here are some related questions, hope this is helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451223/uncertainty-of-parameters-estimated-by-maximum-likelihood/451239#451239

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/491275/does-sampling-more-frequently-reduce-variance/491386#491386